# what is the problem in my selenium - python code?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The Error it is showing:

```
GetHandleVerifier [0x00CBDCE3+50899]
        (No symbol) [0x00C4E111]
        (No symbol) [0x00B55588]
        (No symbol) [0x00B7570C]
        (No symbol) [0x00B71471]
        (No symbol) [0x00B6F479]
        (No symbol) [0x00BA1FFE]
        (No symbol) [0x00BA1CEC]
        (No symbol) [0x00B9B6F6]
        (No symbol) [0x00B77708]
        (No symbol) [0x00B7886D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F23EAE+2566302]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F592B1+2784417]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F5327C+2759788]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D55740+672048]
        (No symbol) [0x00C58872]
        (No symbol) [0x00C541C8]
        (No symbol) [0x00C542AB]
        (No symbol) [0x00C471B7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x74E200F9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FA7BBE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76FA7B8E+238]
```

My Code:

```
##Importing Libraries:
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Kanishk Jain\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://google.com")

    driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    driver.close()
```

Details:- The Above is error and at bottom its my main code which is not running i dont know why pls check pls  pls pls

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you are trying to implement google search, In your code below line is causing the problem

```
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You don't need to click on "Google search" button to start the search

```
search = driver.driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('man city vs southampton')
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.close()
```

I'm just sending the search query using `send_keys()`, And after that again I'm calling same method by sending `ENTER` to start the search

Comment: `##Importing Libraries:
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\Kanishk Jain\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32")


driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://google.com")

search = driver.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys("Man vs Wild")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.close()`



SO I TRIED THIS BUT ITS NOT WORKING STILL PLS CHECK

Comment: Are you getting any errors?